# Deviation in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, c#, web-application, rest-api

I am new to Web API development. I have created a small Web API, which returns a JSON output.

The Web API is running on another PC in the same network. 
I have been connected to the API via GET request for more than an hour and the result looks like the following:

[image]

What is the deviation value suggesting me? Its value is 10 so do I need to be worried about something?

Answer (score 1):

As per [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)

> **Standard Deviation** is a measure of the variability of a data set. This is a standard statistical measure. See, for example: Standard [Deviation entry at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation). JMeter calculates the population standard deviation (e.g. [STDEVP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/stdevp-function-1f7c1c88-1bec-4422-8242-e9f7dc8bb195) function in spreadsheets), not the sample standard deviation (e.g. STDEV).

So basically **10** is the result of applying the standard deviation formula to all response times.

---

With regards to your approach - it doesn't tell the full story, you don't actually create high load as I can only see 2 virtual users. Normally people are interested in answers to 2 questions:

1. Will the application handle the anticipated load providing reasonable response times (so called [load testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_testing)). In this case you need to mimic real-life API usage with JMeter and simulate the number of concurrent users (or applications) accessing your API.
2. When (and why) it will gonna break ([Stress Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing)). In this case you should start with point 1 and gradually increase the load until response time starts exceeding acceptable value or errors start occurring (whatever comes the first)

Check out [Why ‘Normal’ Load Testing Isn’t Enough](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-%E2%80%98normal%E2%80%99-load-testing-isn%E2%80%99t-enough) article to learn more about approaches to testing your API.

Also be aware that you can generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) which provides way more statistical information and interactive charts so you will be able to analyze your test results more easily than using any JMeter Listener.

Comment: I am simulating with 2 users because the API will not be used by many users (only for the internal limited purpose). But as per your suggestion, I will try to increase the number of users. But is there anything which seems problematic with the current report?

Comment: I don't see any issues looking into numbers